# How to use SAX parser for large XML file on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml-parsing, saxparser

I'm going to parse the large XML on Ruby on Rails.
I've checked many solutions, including SAX-parser, but the help link is not working now.
([Using SAX Parser to get several sub-nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14662728/using-sax-parser-to-get-several-sub-nodes))

I'm a newbie. If someone have a code working well, please share for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [Ox](https://github.com/ohler55/ox)

It also has some SAX examples [in the documentation](http://www.ohler.com/ox/#label-SAX+XML+Parsing-3A)

```
require 'stringio'
require 'ox'

class Sample < ::Ox::Sax
  def start_element(name); puts "start: #{name}";        end
  def end_element(name);   puts "end: #{name}";          end
  def attr(name, value);   puts "  #{name} => #{value}"; end
  def text(value);         puts "text #{value}";         end
end

io = StringIO.new(%{
<top name="sample">
  <middle name="second">
    <bottom name="third"/>
  </middle>
</top>
})

handler = Sample.new()
Ox.sax_parse(handler, io)
```